# App switcher observer notification is too much sensitive and causing open socket connections

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, websocket

I am using sockets for some streaming of FX data and I have implemented code where the app will close all the sockets when it enters in the background or some other events such as calls or for the app switcher screen.

```
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
                print("SOCKET: ", "Close socket triggered")
                SIM.sharedCallbackSocket.closeSocket()
                SIM.sharedFeedSocket.closeSocket()
            }
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
                print("App is visible now")
                if userStateViewModel.isAuthenticationDone {
                    let _ = SIM.sharedCallbackSocket.subscribeCallbackChannels()
                    let _ = SIM.sharedFeedSocket.subscribe(scrips: [], subscribeAll: true)
                }
            }
```

but the problem I am facing is about the app switcher screen. The above code is too fast that it gets executed even if the user touches the bottom bar slightly. The time for that alert is too fast which causes the new socket to open before closing the old one and creates hundreds of open sockets which causes my server to close its application pool.

Comment: not sure what your code is doing `The time for the alert is too fast...`, but maybe you could use something like `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(...)` to delay things.

Comment: That's because you are using `willResignActive`. The app switcher is a cancellable gesture and that event will fire when the even begins, not when it is complete. You probably should use `didEnterBackground` as your trigger.  You should then set a flag to indicate that the sockets are closed and only open new sockets in `didBecomeActive` if the flag is set. Be aware that system dialogs can also cause your app to resign active but it is not going into the background.